# How to remove text from Pie chart section in IOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, pie-chart, ios-charts

I am in mid of developing small IOS app using Swift 3. Inside that app, I would like to have a Pie chart. To build a Pie chart, I followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/) link and pie chart is getting generated.

But then I don't want to show the the text inside the pie chart because it doesn't look great/overlap with other text when the area size is very less.

Any idea, how to do it? Those Jan, Feb text should not appear inside the pie chart circle.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to FALSE below properties for chart

```
 chartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
 chartView.usePercentValuesEnabled = false
 chartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
```